# InStrRev() problems

Tags: string, vba

I am trying to write a Do Loop that enters into a long string and returns the place of the space before an email address and the place of the space after. Using InStr() I have been able to locate the end of the email address. Now I need to locate the beginning to then use Mid() to pull the address out. I see that InStrRev() should start at the end of a string and then search, but looking at actual manuals it appears it just gives the second instance of a character. For example:

My string is:

please shoot me an email. My E-Mail: fake@gmail.com If you cannot make it call me.

What I have done so far is returned the place of the @ , which in this case if 42. Then I used InStr() to return the place of the first " " after the @. Which in this case is, 52. I wish to return the place of the first " " BEFORE the @. In this case it should be 37. My plan then is to use Mid(37, 15). Fifteen being the difference of 52 & 37. I have tried using InStrRev() to return 37 but cannot get it to work. Any suggestions? below is my code.

```
x = 2

Do

Cells(x, 11).Select
Cells(x, 11).Value = (InStrRev(Cells(x, 9), Cells(x, 2), " "))

x = x + 1

On Error Resume Next

Loop Until Cells(x, 2).Value = ""
```

Where (x,9) is the place of the @ and (x, 2) is the string.

Answer (score 7):

or maybe if all you need is the email address:

```
Function GetEmail(longstr As String) As String

GetEmail = Filter(Split(longstr, " "), "@")(0)

End Function
```

Generally, looping should be avoided in Excel as it is slow, the below will do what your code does without the loop:

```
Columns(12).Cells(1).Resize(Columns(11).Cells(2).End(xlDown).Row - 1, 1).Offset(1).Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Filter(Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Columns(11).Value), " "), " "), "@"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the +1s, Filter and split are amongst the most useful things in Excel VBA, NB the thing with Filter is that it returns partial matches, which is why it works here, but needs a bit of nifty string manipulation to return only full matches.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
MyArray = Split(Mystring," ")

For i=0 To Ubound(MyArray)
   If Instr(MyArray(i)),"@")>0 Then
       ''Email
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

```
' Find the @ symbol
Dim atPosition As Integer
atPosition = InStr(cellValue, "@")
' check if found here

' Find the space after the @
Dim secondSpacePosition As Integer
secondSpacePosition = InStr(atPosition, cellValue, " ")
' check if found here

' Find the space before the @
Dim firstSpacePosition As Integer
firstSpacePosition = InstrRev(cellValue, " ", atPosition) '  beware, the arguments differ a little
' check if found here

Dim email As String
email = Mid(cellvalue, firstSpacePosition + 1, secondSpacePosition - firstSpacePosition - 1)
```